# Android Volley MalformedURLException Bad URL

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking, okhttp

After making a second network request using `Volley`, I always get this error.  It doesn't seem to matter what the url I put in is.  `Volley` always claims it is malformed.

```
08-04 20:16:26.885  14453-14470/com.thredup.android E/Volley﹕ [994] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:127)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
 Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:101)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
```

Investigating further, I put a couple logs in HurlStack.  In

```
public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders),
```

the request that fails is `REQUEST [ ]  0x0 LOW 26.`"

Thus, line 101 of HurlStack : `URL parsedUrl = new URL(url);`

fails with an empty url (`request.getUrl()` is empty).

I am using `OkHttpStack` (extending HurlStack).
Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: I get this error too, can you explain how you solved this? thanks.

Comment: I m getting this error too, please share the solution in case u have solved it, thanx a lot!

Comment: @Nightly Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: @RevanthRev: I think you should post your code for more information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32245444/4522954 @BNK

Comment: @RevanthRev: your issue has been fixed?

Comment: yes BNK thanks for coming

Comment: Can you add the code where you make your request?

Comment: Toast the url string. is it blank??. if so, is not really a Volley issue if the url is blank

Comment: Add your code snippet too. How you implemented it? Code inside onResponse & errorlistener is not required.

Comment: Is this exception coming in your second request using volley and not in first. If this is the case then this was a bug in volley. Not sure if it fixed now or not.

Comment: Hi @Eric  , Will you accept my answer. So that it wont listead in unanswered questions and helpful for others

Answer (score 19):

actually the problem is with your url not with the volley. Your Url is not a URI. There is no protocol component in it. It needs `http://` or whatever other protocol you intend. If you have the http in your url make sure where it is correctly formed or not.

For example your url formation should be like this

```
public String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
```

Don’t forget to read the [URL Specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) and make sure the URL you are providing is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Make Sure that you have passed the URL as the second parameter in JsonObjectRequest or StringRequest. I made the same mistake which produced the same error like what you faced.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, URL, null, ResponseListener, ErrorListener);
```

Comment: Here i can use JsonArrayRequest I can also face same problem

Answer (score 3):

Use
http://
OR
https://

prefix to your URL
example: 
example.com/information.json
write it as
http://example.com/information.json

Answer (score 2):

this Exception occur while you are hitting an `Url` that is not prefixed   with`http//` or `https//`.so check there is there`http//` is with your URL.
you can get more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963188/overcoming-java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol-exception) and [see](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html)  these links