# Unable to understand the logcat error

Tags: java, android, exception

This is the logcat window. I do not understand the problem. Is this the database error or a server error, because I have checked the code many times. when I add the item to the cart it shows in the logcat. please help to rectify.

thanks in advance.

```
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037): [15630] NetworkDispatcher.run:Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL null
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037): java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL null
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037):at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:127)
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037):at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037): Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: null
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037):at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037):at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037):at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:101)
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037):at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
 01-11 18:07:02.271: E/Volley(29037):... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is coming as null and you are not handling exception also.

```
run:Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL null
```

Answer (score 1):

The Url you are trying to include in your code is either null or invalid which lags protocol like`http://` or `https://` plus you haven't handled any kind of exceptions that are likely to happen in such cases!

I would suggest you to go thru these [Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130745/android-volley-malformedurlexception-bad-url) posted in another thread.