# Volley bad URL - how to fix that?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm having a problem with java volley when I click login

```
  private void Login(){

    String url = "api.matraindonesia.com/login";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.trim().equals("success")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this error:"+ error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email",etEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("password",etPassword.getText().toString().trim());

            return super.getParams();
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

> com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL

Comment: Put http in url and try again like `http://api.matraindonesia.com/login`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130745/android-volley-malformedurlexception-bad-url

Comment: obviously missing URL scheme (`http`, `https`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `http://` or `https://` at the beginning or the `url`

```
String url = "http://api.matraindonesia.com/login";
```

or  if your server is on **SSL**

```
String url = "https://api.matraindonesia.com/login";
```

**Edit** (after your comment) :

typically `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` happen when, route method is not match.

Suppose you define `POST` request route file, but you sending `GET` Request to the route.

Comment: I have error BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://api.matraindonesia.com/login if I use http://